# Clustering HOG features for Bag of Words Visual Model in opencv 3.2 is too slow to be usable. HOG properties?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I am trying to build a visual bag of words model using HOG descriptors. This is part of patch-level background model for foreground-background selection. Following [here](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2013/papers/Ren_Ensemble_Video_Object_2013_CVPR_paper.pdf).

I am using opencv 3.2 binary on windows, python 3.5.

I first create a BOW class with a dictionary size 128:

```
self.BOW=cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(128)
```

I'll be using HOG descriptors with the following parameters (but see below).

```
#HOG descriptor
winSize = (64,64)
blockSize = (16,16)
blockStride = (8,8)
cellSize = (8,8)
nbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = 4.
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 2.0000000000000001e-01
gammaCorrection = 0
nlevels = 32
self.calc_HOG = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins,derivAperture,winSigma,
                        histogramNormType,L2HysThreshold,gammaCorrection,nlevels)
```

I am using MOG background subtraction to generate my initial background proposal, which I then feed into the BOW model for patch-level features.

An image has the following shape

```
self.bg_image.shape
(509, 905, 3)
```

So for each frame, if its been classified as background by MOG I add the HOG feature to the BOW model

```
self.BOW.add(self.calc_HOG.compute(self.bg_image))
```

and I'll go along like that until a potential foreground object needs to be checked.

When a frame is potentially foreground, I cluster the descriptors

```
self.background_vocab=self.BOW.cluster()
```

Generate an extractor

```
 self.extract_bow = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(self.calc_HOG, self.matcher)
```

create a vocabulary

```
  self.extract_bow.setVocabulary(self.background_vocab)
```

and compare the current crop to the current background image

```
  current_BOWhist=self.extract_bow.compute(current)

  print("Extract background HOG feature")
  background_BOWhist=self.extract_bow.compute(background)

  print("Compare Background and Foreground Masks")
  BOW_dist =cv2.compareHist(current_BOWhist, background_BOWhist, method=cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR)
```

The memory use/performance of this often cited strategy seems completely unusable. the BOW.cluster() method, documented [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d72/classcv_1_1BOWKMeansTrainer.html#a2b6df61c3df97122eb50c417455b5bac) is incredibly memory intensive and basically locks up the computer. Even on just a few descriptors it takes 10 to 20 seconds. This is especially perplexing because the above paper, and many similar papers, specify that the background model is *continuously* updated, that is, many calls of cluster() and generating new a vocabulary.

So in my example file, I go through 30 frames of adding HOG features

```
a=self.BOW.getDescriptors()
len(a)
30
```

Which has alot of descriptors (clue here?)

```
self.BOW.descriptorsCount()
576979200
```

I think is the problem, this seems like way too many points for kmeans. Is there something wrong with my HOG descriptor properties? From the cited paper above

"The BoW dictionary size is 128. During the verification step, the MSDPs are resized according to their aspect ratios to make sure all patches contain roughly the same amount of pixels. In order to tackle with the various aspect ratios, which is inevitable during segmentation, we let the number of HOG grids along x and y coordinates to be flexible while keeping the total number to be a fixed number of 600. Similarly, an overall 25 blocks are used to encode the HOG features. The HOG dimension is 32"

What am I not understanding about how HOG features are added to bag of words?